# Excel sorting / grouping rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, export-to-excel

Is it possible to group poems in Excel, mark them as 'whole'?

I would like that after turning on filtering and sorting, e.g. A-Z, cells for one category would not get mixed up, they would be sorted together. Merge cells is not an option.

this is how I would like the cells to look like after A-Z filtering (selected the area of a given category with colors) / this is how they currently look:

[image]

[image]

I don't want cells from different categories (colors) to get mixed up when sorting

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more?  Better yet, show a screenshot of what you want the result to look like based on the sample you've provided.  I'm confused as to what you're asking for.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly it's just a matter of selecting all sortable columns when setting the filter and then sort on column A like you did. It'll sort all columns that are part of the set filter in given order.

Comment: @P.b: and how to do that? When you don't fill in anything in those other columns, they won't be selected while creating a filter or while sorting, only the filled cells are taken into account (which, I believe, is exactly the problem of the author).

Comment: If you want to have a blank, uncolored row between categories, you will need to use VBA.  Otherwise, depending on your version of Excel, you can either sort the column by Color and contents; or add a column to the table that specifies the category, and sort by the Category column and the contents.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer to explain one way to do this.

You can sort a list by colour; however the caveat is you can only sort by one colour at a time.

[image: Sort by colour]

So it would have to be a **VBA** solution, and you would need to build up an array of the colours in the column then loop through the array, placing each colour at the top until the entire list is sorted.